# Is it possible to configure a NSTableView to have Sections?

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I would like to create a Table View to display a list of items that users can click to start actions and would like to visually group them in categories.

In iOS is relatively easy have sections in a Table View but in macOS I haven't find documentation about this.

I found this article by Marcin Krzyżanowski of May 2015 http://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2015/05/29/lets-talk-about-sections-for-nstableview/, it's excellent but I would like to implement a simpler solution to avoid problems when maintaining code I don't understand well.

Comment: it is better to go for an `NSCollectionView` and you can create a custom layout which mimics the table view's look; I always do that and the final result is just perfect.

Comment: NSOutlineView will do sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't managed to find a way to use sections in `NSTableView` either, and I like your approach...don't just copy and paste code you don't understand :)

What I have done when I needed sections in a macOS app was to use the "new" `NSCollectionView` (https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscollectionview) (it has been around since 10.5 but got a major overhaul in 10.11). It is somewhat similar to `UICollectionView` and gives you the ability to use sections.

So...

Instead of `UICollectionViewDataSource` you have `NSCollectionViewDataSource` (https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscollectionviewdatasource) 
where you can use `numberOfSections(in:)` and `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)` for instance. Furthermore you have `makeSupplementaryView(ofKind:withIdentifier:for:)` which can be used to create your section header views.

[This tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/120494/collection-views-os-x-tutorial) from Ray Wenderlich is worth having a look at.

I know it is not exactly what you were looking for but maybe you can use it. Good luck :)